# I want to setup a RLS using this table in Power BI Embedded where I am only fetching Scheme Code as userprincipalname()

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I am looking to setup RLS in Power BI Embedded using below table where SCHEMECODE should be my userprincipalname() and through the webapp user can have multiple SCHEMECODE's which will be comma separated. This is an example of what I will be getting from the webapp ***"16856,39760"***

[image: Table Screenshot]

Comment: what have you tried and whats is going wrong?

Comment: The problem is my website provides me comma separated multiple values for SCHEMECODE & I need to filter all those individual rows from above table. I do not have clue how to set SCHEMECODE as my userprincipalname() for comma separated values. I do not have any email_username with this data model. Only thing I have to use is above SCHEMECODE.

Answer (score 0):

What you may try is to split your string into table of separate values;
Then in RLS 'YourTable'[SCHEMACODE] in TableOf (code below);

```
EVALUATE

VAR _userprincipalname  = "16856,39760"

VAR SplitByCharacter = ","
VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", _userprincipalname ),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word])
RETURN
    Table0
```

[image]